# How to get svn history from google code

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a project hosted at code.google.com. I would like to get the history of commits to the svn repository. I have tortoise svn installed. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: do you want to *download* the history or just *see* it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, thanks for your answers. However, I've found myself a way to do what I wanted and that's extremely easy.

In order to have a txt historty of the commits to the svn, I just had to go the Tortoise SVN ->Show log, select the versions I wanted, right click and choose the option copy to clipboard. Voila!

Answer (score 3):

Use the [svnsync](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.ref.svnsync.html) tool, as explained in the [code.google.com FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/SubversionFAQ#How_do_I_download_my_Subversion_history?).

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on your check-out folder, Tortoise SVN -> Show log (provided you have the context menu extension installed).

Comment: I have already done that, but that doesn't allow to export the data, I believe.

Comment: That is unlikely, you can checkout all the revisions - there is no reason the log shouldn't be working.

Comment: When I say export the data I mean to export the log, not the code, to a txt. Is there a way to do that?